# XWiki: StackOverflowError while importing XAR

Tags: xwiki

I updated my xwiki to Version 8.2.1. After that I get an StackOverflowError everytime I try to upload a XAR. Does anyone have any idea where this comes from?

```
    14:39:05.955 [https://localhost/ xwiki /bin/get/XWiki/XWikiPreferences?xpage=packagedescriptor&package=org.xwiki.platform_xwiki-platform-administration-ui-8.2.1.xar] ERROR org.xwiki.velocity.tools.JSONTool - Failed to serialize object to JSON
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.xwiki.model.reference.EntityReference["reversedReferenceChain"]->java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.xwiki.model.reference.EntityReference["reversedReferenceChain"]->java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.xwiki.model.reference.EntityReference["reversedReferenceChain"]->java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.xwiki.model.reference.EntityReference["reversedReferenceChain"]->java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.xwiki.model.reference.EntityReference["reversedReferenceChain"]->java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.xwiki.model.reference.EntityReference["reversedReferenceChain"]->[…]) 
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:677) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
[…]

14:39:05.968 [https://localhost/xwiki/bin/get/XWiki/XWikiPreferences?xpage=packagedescriptor&package=org.xwiki.platform_xwiki-platform-administration-ui-8.2.1.xar] DEBUG o.x.v.internal.DefaultVelocityEngine - Null reference [template '76:/templates/packagedescriptor.vm', line 36, column 4] : $jsontool.serialize($json) cannot be resolved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to suggest that you have a version of Jackson older than the one which is supposed to be provided in XWiki WAR. One that does not support @Transient which is used to skip serialization of EntityReference#getReversedReferenceChain().

Maybe your application server bring an older version of Jackson and you need to isolate XWiki properly.

Comment: Alternatively if the update was done by just unpacking the newer *.war over the older one, the older versions of the libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`  will still be present and might confuse the application about which version to use.